Since corollaries of ZFC are r.e.，why there are Turing degrees that are not r.e.?
for any Turing degree a and A∈a，and a fixed x,we can just put the formula “x∈A” into the Turing machine which examines whether a formula is a corollary of ZFC.It halts iff ZFC proves “x∈A”.So we got that every Turing degree is at most r.e. What's wrong with this conclusion?

edited
Here we choose ZFC as metalanguage and x∈A could be rewritten as some \phi(x).In this case,our definition of r.e.  set are organized under ZFC so we do not consider if ZFC cannot prove \phi(x).
However if we do so,there are two different turing machines(one in metalanguage and one in object language),the former says "it is r.e.".and the latter says it not(if we choose A as not r.e set),that's what confuses me because Church-Turing thesis says they both agree with  our concept about computation.

edited
What I mean is that we are working in the language of set theory(LST) and in this case what ever we say about sets we actully write a formula. e.g.,by saying "X is countable" we mean $ZFC \vdash $"$ \exists f:\omega \rightarrow X$ and $f is 1-1$".To make that "definable argument" go through we must define a new formal language in LST (and that's where model theory begins),and in this language we reformalize $\lceil ZFC \rceil $  and can finilly consider provability in ZFC.But this sidetracks too far, I take a concrete example.Let $\boldsymbol\varphi(\boldsymbol x)$ be a $\Sigma_2$ formula (in the formal language) and let$A=\{a\in HF|HF\models \boldsymbol\varphi(\boldsymbol a)\}$, we just write $\phi(a)$ (in LST) for "$a\in HF$ and $HF\models \varphi(a)$",and $ZFC \vdash \exists !y (x \in y \iff \phi(x))$.So we just use this $A$.

What if $A$ has no definition in ZFC? Also what if $x\in A$ but ZFC can’t prove it?

Here we choose ZFC as metalanguage and x∈A could be rewritten as some \phi(x).In this case,our definition of r.e.  set are organizationed under ZFC so wo do not consider if ZFC cannot prove \phi(x).

There are only countably many r.e. sets and only countably many formulas in the language of set theory. You can't just take an arbitrary $A\subseteq \mathbb N$ and then say there's some set theory formula expressing $x\in A$. (And I don't see any reason why we are absolved from considering provability in ZFC just because we're working in ZFC.)

I'm sorry I don't make it clear.I  supplied some explanation.Thank you!

Yes, if the set is nicely definable in some way, then we move on the the second objection... I can't really improve on Noah's answer in terms of substantiating that further.

I see.Thank you!

There is no tension here. (For simplicity, I'll focus on explaining how there can be sets which are not r.e. rather than Turing degrees.)
Take for example the usual definition $\varphi$ of the complement of the halting problem, $H^c$. The set $$\varphi^\mathsf{ZFC}:=\{x:\mathsf{ZFC}\vdash\varphi(x)\}$$ is a c.e. subset of $H^c$ (I'm assuming $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is sound here for simplicity), but is much smaller than $H^c$ itself. If we replace $\mathsf{ZFC}$ with a stronger (sound) theory $T$ the corresponding c.e. subset $\varphi^T$ may be larger but will still fall short of $H^c$.
If you adopt a formalist standpoint and only care about things that are provable in $\mathsf{ZFC}$, as you seem to be doing per the comments, then you may indeed reject $H^c$ as a "meaningful" mathematical object. However, you will still have to deal with the fact that $$\varphi^\mathsf{ZFC}\not= H^c$$ is expressible and provable in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ itself - as is "$H^c$ is not c.e.," for that matter. (Interestingly, $\mathsf{ZFC}$ does not prove "$\varphi^\mathsf{ZFC}\subsetneq H^c$" since that statement implies - indeed, is equivalent to - the consistency of $\mathsf{ZFC}$.)

Oh I see, does that mean although${x:ZFC \vdash \varphi(x)}$ is c.e., $ZFC \vdash “{x:\varphi(x)} is not c.e."$        that is amazing.

@jtxsxlm Yup, that's correct. Think of it this way: every "reasonable" theory (like $\mathsf{ZFC}$) provides a way to approximate an arbitrary "definable" set by a c.e. set, but that approximation might be crud and the theory might know that.

I see.Thank you!
